# Tomcat8.5　で動くSpringBootプロジェクトの作り方を教えてください。

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Spring Boot starterで特定のTomcatで動くアプリケーションを作りたいです。

Eclipseをインストールし、SpringBootStarter で新規プロジェクトを作ったのですが、デフォルトでEclipse9.0 が埋め込まれており、
違うバージョンのものが実装できないようです。

pom.xmlを以下のように変えたところ

```
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<tomcat.version>8.5.32</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

Springプロジェクトで、War/Jar出力時、開発環境のビルドで 特定のTomcatバージョンで動くものを作る方法を教えてください。

エラーLog

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:175)

The following method did not exist:
```

Answer (score 0):

- [2.2.1. Servlet Containers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements-servlet-containers)

> You can also deploy Spring Boot applications to any Servlet 3.1+ compatible container.

とある通り、Sevlet3.1以降に対応したサーブレットコンテナに対してデプロイ可能です。

これは[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)のバージョンで言うと 8.0 以降になります。
つまり特に何もせずとも Tomcat8.5上にデプロイ可能なはずです。

---

組み込みTomcatのバージョンを8.5としたいのであれば、[Spring Boot 2.0.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements-servlet-containers)を利用する必要があります。
(ただし古いバージョンの組み込みTomcatを必要とする場面は通常発生しないのではないかと思います)

なお2.0.xのサポートは終了しています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Tomcatを8.5にすると下記エラーがでて9.0以上に戻すと直ります。。。TomcatのバージョンがAn attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:175)

The following method did not exist:

Comment: Tomcatを別途用意してそこへデプロイして動作させたい、というのであれば、そのバージョンはデフォルトのままで問題ありません(8.5にする必要はありません)。